# DateTimeFormatter ofPattern not working for "L"

Tags: date-formatting, java-time, localdatetime, datetimeformatter

I have a LocalDateTime object and I would like to format this, to have printouts like:

**Tue 23. Nov**. Therefore, I used a `DateTimeFormatter` like:

```
val formatter: DateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("e dd. LLL")
```

But unfortunately I get **Tue 23. 11** The month is a number and no letters!?

Comment: Can you use MMM instead of LLL I looked at from this website [link](https://www.java67.com/2019/01/10-examples-of-format-and-parse-dates-in-java.html)

Comment: What is you default locale? BTW `LLL` is wrong here anyway, at least in the locales where I have met it.

Comment: Funnily in my locale (da-DK) I get `2 23. nov`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct format pattern string is `E dd. MMM`. Excuse my Java syntax.

```
private static final DateTimeFormatter DATE_FORMATTER 
        = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("E dd. MMM", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Also remember to specify desired locale for your formatter.

Trying it out:

```
    LocalDate date = LocalDate.of(2021, Month.NOVEMBER, 23);
    String formatted = date.format(DATE_FORMATTER);
    System.out.println(formatted);
```

Output is the desired:

> Tue 23. Nov

Spelling out how my format pattern is different:

- I am using upper case `E` for the abbreviation of the day of week. Lower case `e` should give you the number of the day of week like `2` for Tuesday. `eee` should work for the abbreviation too.
- I am using `MMM` for the abbreviation of the month. `LLL` is for the *standalone* form. Some languages use a different form of the month depending on whether the day of month is present or not. A language may for example use the nominative for the month alone and the genetive with a day number, a bit the differene between *November* and ***of** November*. Since you have the day included, you should not use pattern letter `L` here. Funnily for some languages that have *not* got a stand-alone form (like English), Java gives you the number instead when you specify `LLL`.

Edit: you asked:

> How would that look for "November" fully written out? "MMM" works for
> "Dec."

The documentation that you linked to in another comment gives the answer:

> **Text**: The text style is determined based on the number of pattern letters used. Less than 4 pattern letters will use the `short form`.
> Exactly 4 pattern letters will use the `full form`. …

So use `MMMM` instead of `MMM`:

```
private static final DateTimeFormatter DATE_FORMATTER 
        = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("E dd. MMMM", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

> Tue 23. November

Documentation link: [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html)

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html M/L is number/text

Comment: Ole V.V How would that look for "November" fully written out? "MMM" works for "Dec."

Comment: Please see my edit, @RalfWickum